# Why was the radio button feature not implemented in ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

Do you know why the RadioButton feature was not implemented? I know that there are some extensions for it. However as CheckBox was implemented, I would expect that RadioButton would also be implemented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a pull request pending on radio buttons. Looking at the comments and related PR's will give you a nice history of radio buttons and EmberJS.

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1235